# Gluon Mobile ScrollPane Optimization

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I'm trying to implement a JavaFX ScrollPane with a nested VBox, and I'm experience a strange issue when scrolling too fast in mobile. The issue is that if I scroll in smaller yet quick upward gestures, the scrollpane stalls for a half a second first, and then continues. It gets laggy in random swipe gestures. Is there anyway I can optimize this?

This doesn't happen on the desktop version, so I'm guessing it may be a limitation of my phone and JavaFX itself. **This issue is more evident when I set a background image for the scroll pane viewport.** Here is some sample code for a View:

```
public class StackUserView extends View {

    private Label label;

    public StackUserView(String name) {
        super(name);
        initDisplay();
    }

    private void initDisplay() {
        this.label = new Label("10");
        label.setFont(Font.font(40d));
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.setSpacing(10);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            Label label = new Label("HELLO");
            label.setCache(true);
            label.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
            label.setCacheShape(true);
            box.getChildren().add(label);
        }

        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(box);
        pane.setCacheHint(CacheHint.QUALITY);
        pane.setFitToHeight(true);
        pane.setFitToHeight(true);

        this.setCenter(pane);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer(SpeedSelect.MENU_LAYER)));
        appBar.setTitleText(this.getName());
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
    }

}
```

Ultimately, I am trying to get it to scroll as close as possible to the actual native mobile environments.

I have been able to optimize situations where scrolling is desired creating a custom CharmListView with HBox's as cells, but then I can't use SceneBuilder for my views which affects maintainability.

Note: I am using an LG G5 for testing.

Here is a short video of the issue. You can see after the swipe. The scroll stops for a second and then continues:

[image: Scroll lag display.]

Comment: I haven't tested your code yet, but why do you say the you can't use CharmListView with Scene Builder? So far, ListView/CharmListView controls are precisely intended for virtualization and reuse of just a few cells. And, in case of mobile, CharmListView is actually an optimized ListView.

Comment: I can surely add the CharmListView in SceneBuilder, but how do I add an HBox to it in SceneBuilder? For other situations in this application I have actually resorted to hard coding an HBox list view that extends a CharmListView. However, most of the views in this application are done using SceneBuilder with FXML injection so I want to limit how much hard coding required for the view generation. It's not a long list. Just long enough to not be able to be fit in the view. The above code snippet is just some sample code to recreate the issue. Not the actual code.

Comment: It's not really a list either. It's just a long form that can overflow depending on the size of the device viewing it.

Comment: Like a regular ListView, a CharmListView uses a ListCell implementation. Neither of them support cells in Scene Builder. So that can't be accomplished there. But if it doesn't fit as a list either, then you need another solution indeed.

Comment: My guess is that you are affected by [this bug](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/90/unnecessary-creation-of-font_map-for-every). Sadly, it seems no one is too interested in fixing it.

Comment: @sillyfly that would be unfortunate if true. That would mean that this bug would persist in any situation that scrolling is desired on a mobile device without using a list view. I would think that would be a severe limitation.

Comment: You misunderstand. This bug affects any and every text rendering on the Android port of JavaFX, regardless of container. `ListView` won't be much better than `ScrollPane` in this sense. If you are able to compile your own version of the JFX port - the workaround is fairly simple. Otherwise - a relatively more complicated workaround is needed to change the `FontFactory` through reflection.

Comment: Ah I see. i don't know of that is entirely the issue in my case then as it persists in both Android and iOS.

Comment: @sillyfly JavaFXPorts on Android uses FreeType, not Pango. I don't think the issue you have linked has anything to do with this one.

Comment: @JoséPereda it uses both. Pango uses FreeType as the underlying mechanism. The bug is *not* in Pango, but rather in how JavaFX uses it. If you look at the [code of the FTFactory](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/src/908fdd99f57582bd41f16a01fa7c50001225ca51/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/font/freetype/FTFactory.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) you will see it creates a `PangoGlyphLayout`.

Comment: @sillyfly Are you referring to this [PrismFontFactory.java](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/src/c250ec48db3b49239c95f46cbb94d6d439822a36/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/font/PrismFontFactory.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#PrismFontFactory.java-49,184:185,232,236)? No sign of Pango there. If you check the log of an Android app you'll find something like `Loading FontFactory com.sun.javafx.font.freetype.FTFactory` and `Freetype2 Loaded (version 2.6.5)`. Or if you check the apk, you'll find this library `libjavafx_font_freetype.so`.

Comment: @sillyfly Anyway let's not discuss the Pango issue here, as this question is related to something completely different.

Comment: @JoséPereda I was able to optimize the scrolling even further as there were some UI glitches with the last code I posted. Let me know of any areas you may find improvement.

Comment: @A.Sharma Yes I saw your answer. Just added mine. Can you check if it works for you as well?

Comment: Jose, this works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by A.Sharma solves some issues as it removes completely the underlying implementation of the built-in `ScrollPane` event handling.

Of course, to solve the issue definitely, a proper solution is required in JavaFXPorts.

In the meantime, another possible approach, that works more closely with the exiting implementation can be done by tackling the problem directly in `ScrollPaneSkin`, which in turn is the class responsible for the event handling for the control.

The class can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/src/782321deae1723ee7f3338d3993435d7b7076258/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/ScrollPaneSkin.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

The good news is that this class can be cloned to your project (i.e `MyScrollPaneSkin`), modified and added as *new* skin for the exiting `ScrollPane` control.

Possible fix

After some tests, the culprit of the issue can be located in the `contentsToViewTimeline` animation. It performs a 1.35 second pause to:

> block out 'aftershocks'

Then there is this line inside the scroll event handler, that checks if the animation has ended and only updates the scrollbar position after that:

```
if (!(((ScrollEvent)event).isInertia()) || (((ScrollEvent)event).isInertia()) && 
    (contentsToViewTimeline == null || 
     contentsToViewTimeline.getStatus() == Status.STOPPED)) {
    vsb.setValue(newValue);
    ...
}
```

While this animation shouldn't be removed, the scrollbar should be updated even when the animation is in idle.

I've made the following change, replacing lines 517-527 with:

```
    /*
    ** if there is a repositioning in progress then we only
    ** set the value for 'real' events
    */
    if ((newValue <= vsb.getMax() && newValue >= vsb.getMin())) {
        vsb.setValue(newValue);
    }
    boolean stop = ! ((ScrollEvent) event).isInertia() || ((ScrollEvent) event).isInertia() && (contentsToViewTimeline == null || contentsToViewTimeline.getStatus() == Status.STOPPED);
    if ((newValue > vsb.getMax() || newValue < vsb.getMin()) && (!mouseDown && !touchDetected) && stop) {
        startContentsToViewport();
    }
    if (stop) {
        event.consume();
    }
```

On your project, now replace the built-in skin:

```
 ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(box);
 pane.setSkin(new MyScrollPaneSkin(pane));
```

I've tested it on Android and iOS and in both cases the animation is smooth and there is not trace of the issue at hand.

Also, these properties might help (use a `java.custom.properties` added to `/src/main/resources`):

```
gluon.experimental.performance=true
com.sun.javafx.gestures.scroll.inertia.velocity=2000
```

It this works, it could be submitted to the JavaFXPorts issue or as a PR.

Comment: José for the custom properties file..is the only thing required for that just inputting it into the resources folder? Or do I have to reference it anywhere in the Java code as well?

Comment: Or can I just set it with the System.setProperties() method?

Comment: Just add the properties file with that given name.

Answer (score 1):

So I kind of hacked a fix for this by consuming the native scroll event and customizing it. **I essentially used a trial-and-error method to figure out what hard (factors below) values I needed to make it scroll OK.**

```
private SimpleDoubleProperty location = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private SimpleDoubleProperty vValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
private SimpleLongProperty startTime = new SimpleLongProperty();
private SimpleLongProperty timer = new SimpleLongProperty();
private double height = MobileApplication.getInstance().getGlassPane().getHeight();
private Animation animation;
private Animation callbackAnimation;

private void scrollOverride() {

    sp.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, event -> {
        event.consume();
    });

    sp.setOnTouchPressed(e -> {

        if (callbackAnimation != null){
            callbackAnimation.stop();
        }

        if (animation != null) {
            animation.stop();
        }

        vValue.set(sp.vvalueProperty().get());
        location.set(e.getTouchPoint().getY());
        startTime.set((new Date()).getTime());

    });

    sp.setOnTouchMoved(e -> {
        timer.set((new Date()).getTime());
    });

    sp.setOnTouchReleased(e -> {

        Boolean dontOverride = false;

        double deltaTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime.get();
        double deltaY = sp.vvalueProperty().get() - vValue.get();

        if(Math.abs(deltaY) < 0.05){
            dontOverride = true;
        }

        double translation = deltaY / (deltaTime/300);

        double value = 0d;

        if (Math.abs(timer.get() - startTime.get()) < 500) {
            value = sp.vvalueProperty().get() + translation;
        } else {
            value = sp.vvalueProperty().get();
            dontOverride = true;
        }

        animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(deltaTime + 100),
                        new KeyValue(sp.vvalueProperty(), value)));

        animation.play();

        if (!dontOverride) {
            animation.setOnFinished(evt -> {
                boolean innerUp = (sp.vvalueProperty().get() - vValue.get()) < 0;

                int innerSign = 1;

                if (innerUp) {
                    innerSign = -1;
                }

                callbackAnimation = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(deltaTime + 150),
                                new KeyValue(sp.vvalueProperty(), sp.vvalueProperty().get() + (0.1 * innerSign), Interpolator.EASE_OUT)));
                callbackAnimation.play();
            });
        }

    });
}
```

You can limit this override to only happen on mobile devices by doing the following:

```
if(!com.gluonhq.charm.down.Platform.isDesktop()){
   scrollOverride();
}
```

If anybody can optimize this or come up with their own solution, that would be great. Again, **my goal was primarily to prevent that laggy stop from occuring when scrolling.**

Within the application on my iPhone 7+, this is actually working very well. It works comparably well as when I inject a browser into the app with a web view.